# How can I ensure my resources get redirected correctly? (Apache/PHP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, slim

Hello good people of the internet. I'm currently using the MicroPHP framework, Slim with XAMPP. Maybe this problem doesn't exist in a standard linux LAMP server, but whatever.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

As per the documentation, I have set up the .htaccess and the actual REST redirection to the site address works, but the additional, root level, resources (such as image, js, css files) do not get redirected.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Has the !, meaning that the redirection occurs if the file DOESN'T exist.

I understand the logic, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I get my resources to redirect to the right location?

Folder breakdown

```
/**index.php**
/css
/images
/Slim
```

and so on.

Any direct index.php requests get their resources properly - e.g. *127.0.0.1/* or *127.0.0.1/index.php*

The problem occurs when using the mythical /user/SacredSkull URL, which does perform the correct function and pulls the right user off the database, but all the HTTP resources get left out to dry.

I'm not going to be surprised if the answer is obvious or already answered (I did try to find this before hand to no avail - probably because of the Slim ruby templating results screwing things up). Please be gentle :( I've always used apache rewrites with a very long pole.

Comment: Yes, `!-f` means *only redirect if the requested URL is not a physical file*. So `/css/file/that/exists.css` *should* yield the CSS file without going through `index.php`. Is that not the case?

Comment: No, the pages that are yielded are unstyled - the CSS file is in a folder in the index.php directory, so should be accessible...

The directory "user" in foo.bar/user/ is a fake routing directory, and it seems to be looking for such a file in that fake folder

Comment: Bit of an ugly solution, but adding a '/' in front of any resource (e.g. '/styles.css') makes it work.. I guess apache is only seeing relative paths as "real" files?

Comment: So your problem was simply that your URLs were wrong? If you're on `/foo/bar` and you include a CSS file `css/style.css`, the browser will request `/foo/bar/css/style.css`. Relative vs. absolute URL resolution...!